# Can I prove that from a set of ciphertexts one is encrypting $g^0$ and the others are encrypting $g^b$ where $b$ is a negative value?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

Consider for example this set of encrypted values under the Elgamal keys $y_0$,$y_1$,$y_2$: $$
Enc_{y0}(g^0),Enc_{y1}(g^{-20}),Enc_{y2}(g^{-10})
$$
Can I prove that one value is $g^0$ and the others are $g^b$ where b is negative without revealing which one is who?

Comment: You are encrypted not 0 but 1, $g^0$. Anyway 0 itself is not an element of domain group and thus does not work with El gamal, the ciphertext will always be 0. But the main problem with your question is it does not clarify what counts as negative. $g$ lies between 0 and the group order $q-1$, one way is shifting it back by $(q-1)/2$ and define domain between 0$(q-1)/2$ and $(q-1)/2$. Either way, you must make it clear first

Comment: Well there are protocols for AND and OR composition of sigma protocols and one naive solution is proving $ ([0] \land [-ve] \land [-ve]) \lor  ([-ve] \land [0] \land [-ve]) \lor   ([-ve] \land [-ve] \land [0]) $ but others might have better solution

Comment: @ManishAdhikari thanks I fixed it.What i mean is the power of g

Comment: For $g^0$, the corresponding ciphertext is $(g^r, 1\cdot h^r)$, you can prove that $PK\{r: c_1=g^r , c_2=h^r\}$. But for the negative number, I have no idea.